# too many synonyms per synonym ring - Oracle Text

Tags: oracle, oracle-text

I created my own thesaurus for Arabic language and created relations between terms to define synonyms, I used This Code:

```
  ctx_thes.create_thesaurus ('myThesurus');
  ctx_thes.create_relation ('myThesurus', 'لعب', 'syn', 'مرح');
```

it worked fine, I created more than 10000 synonyms.
but when I used this code:

```
SELECT CTX_THES.SYN ('هم', 'plagThesurus') FROM DUAL;
```

it returned this error message

```
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-11702: too many synonyms per synonym ring
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.CTX_THES", line 708
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I searched many, but I couldn't find any results
any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have exceeded the limit. From oracle docs  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCREF/cthes.htm#CCREF2157

> **CREATE_RELATION**  Creates a relation between two phrases in the
>   thesaurus. The synonym ring is limited in **length to about 4000**
>   synonyms, depending on word length.

Comment: thanks, but  4000 synonyms as a total ? or for one term? it is too small for all terms, we are talking about a full language synonyms.

Comment: Looks like for a word. Do you have many of them on one word? @أحمدصوالحة

Comment: I have created 30K synonym pairs, and it's ok. @أحمدصوالحة

Comment: May be some trouble with arabic text processing?

Comment: some of terms worked for me, some are not working, is there any restrictions on syn in oracle text such as ( space if they are two word..etc)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75965/discussion-between-agent5566-and--).